# How to convert Keypair.secret_key to Phantom compatible private key in python?

Tags: phantom, keypair, solana-py, solana-keygen, base58

**CODE**

```
keypair = Keypair.generate()
key = keypair.secret_key
```

This secret key isn't compatible in phantom wallet.
I figured that the `phantom` private key can be converted to `Keypair` compatible secret key by converting the first 32 bytes of the private key to `base58`.

```
base58.b58decode(phantom_key[:32])
```

My question is how do I do the opposite i.e. convert `Keypair` secret key to `Phantom` compatible private key?

Answer (score 1):

`Keypair.generate()` generates a 64 byte key. To get the private key which is compatible with Phantom, use `base58.base58encode()`.

```
 import base58
 keypair = Keypair.generate()
 phantom_key = base58.b58encode(keypair.secret_key)
```

If we `b58encode` only the last 32 bytes, we get the public key.

```
pub_key = base58.b58encode(keypair.secret_key[32:]) # same as keypair.public_key
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this today and the issue for me was with how I was generating the PrivateKey. The private key is a combination of the private+public key in bytes and this is then base 58 decoded here is my solution below.

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client, Keypair
import base58
from dotenv import dotenv_values

config = dotenv_values(".env")
client = Client(config["RPC_URL"])  #You can directly use the RPC_URL here without using dotenv

# Check if the client is connected to the cluster
if client:
    print("Connected to Solana cluster.")
else:
    print("Unable to connect to Solana cluster.")
new_account = Keypair()
#print(new_account.pubkey(), new_account.secret())`
wallet_address = new_account.pubkey()

private_key_bytes = new_account.secret()
public_key_bytes = bytes(new_account.pubkey())
encoded_keypair= private_key_bytes+public_key_bytes
private_key= base58.b58encode(encoded_keypair).decode()
print("Wallet Address: ",wallet_address)
print("Private Key: ",private_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Keypair.generate()` doesn't even exist anymore, and the class itself has been moved into solders.py, here's an up-to-date(solana.py v0.32, solders v0.20) solution:

I tried all of this and a lot more, and noticed that `Keypair.secret()` doesn't look right. Because I assumed `Keypair.secret()` is the key. But it's only 32 bytes, and the key is 64 bytes.

As seen in the auto-tests here, `solders.keypair.Keypair` can actually be type-cast to bytes: `bytes(Keypair())`
https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/16656d9e508c5ed9bd237fd94a1c7bfa45eef9be/tests/test_keypair.py#L26

Doing so gives you the full 64 bytes of the private key.

```
# typecast whole Keypair object, not just Keypair.secret(). Very obvious, I know.
rawPK = bytes(solders.keypair.Keypair()) 
pk = base58.b58encode(rawPK).decode()
```

To then restore a keypair from this private key:

```
keypair = solders.keypair.Keypair.from_base58_string(pk)
```

Here's a complete example of how to export and import back a keypair:

```
import base58
import solders

keypair = solders.keypair.Keypair() # generates new keypair
generatedAddr = keypair.pubkey()

rawPK = bytes(keypair) 
pk = base58.b58encode(rawPK).decode()

restoredKeypair = solders.keypair.Keypair.from_base58_string(pk)
restoredAddr = restoredKeypair.pubkey()
restoredCorrectly = (restoredAddr == generatedAddr)
print(restoredCorrectly)
```

[@Henry Tirla](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/7202/henry-tirla) also already faced the same issue and got the right idea in his answer, but of course this is Solana SO, so I have 0 rep here and can't do anything. Awesome idea to add so much separation to blockchain sub-Stacks.